# Deposit and Withdraw using Fireblocks NCW API

Tags: fireblocks-sdk, fireblocks-api

I want to perform deposit and withdraw functionalities in my app using Fireblocks NCW APIs. Please help finding the suitable API for this.

I have checked the NCW section of APIs on https://developers.fireblocks.com/reference/api-overview.
I am unable to find the suitable API for deposit and withdrawal.